# MySQL stored procedures in SVN

Tags: mysql, svn, stored-procedures, dump

What is the best way to save MySQL stored procedures and table structures in SVN?

I have around 100 tables and 200 stored procedures, dumping all procedures in a single file makes no sense as it contains thousands of lines and hard to maintain. I'm now thinking of creating separate separate files for each table and procedure, but it will sum up to 300 files.

Any suggestions..

Comment: I would dump the table creation clauses into one file and the procedures into separate files. Maybe, if the procedures are real small and have some grouping factor (regard to a same table for instance), I'd group a few procedures into one file where applicable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only played with this, rather than used it in anger, but [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) appears to work quite well.

Comment: I second the use of liquibase. Allows you to control the database changes incrementally, which works hand-in-glove with keeping such changes under subversion revision control